# Windows Server 2016 not showing optional updates

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

I have a Windows Server 2016 *(Standard)* machine that i keep updated:

[image]

Turns out there are a lot of *"Optional Updates"* that never appear in Windows Update.

Today i **happened** to try [Windows Admin Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/overview), which creates a web-site on your machine that can then connect to different servers.

The Admin Center showed me that my servers have some years old **Optional Updates** that don't appear in Windows Update:

[image]

- Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901
- Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) Gaussian Mixture Model - 1911
- Microsoft Silverlight (KB4481252)
- 2020-01 Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4494175)
- SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 4 KB4548597

Which brings the questions:

- Why is Windows Update not showing updates?
- How do i access updates in the Windows Server 2016 user interface?
- How do i access the old (functional) Windows Update in Windows Server 2016?

### Bonus Chatter

Powershell script to display all updates that aren't installed:

## Powershell script

```
Write-Output "Creating Microsoft.Update.Session COM object" 
$session1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

Write-Output "Creating Update searcher" 
$searcher = $session1.CreateUpdateSearcher()

Write-Output "Searching for missing updates..." 
$result = $searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

#Updates are waiting to be installed 
$updates = $result.Updates;

Write-Output "Found $($updates.Count) updates!" 

$updates | Format-Table Title, AutoSelectOnWebSites, IsDownloaded, IsHiden, IsInstalled, IsMandatory, IsPresent, AutoSelection, AutoDownload -AutoSize

pause
```

Example output:

```
Creating Microsoft.Update.Session COM object
Creating Update searcher
Searching for missing updates...
Found 6 updates!

Title                                                                                                               AutoSelectOnWebSites IsDownloaded IsHiden IsInstalled IsMandatory IsPresent AutoSelection AutoDownload
-----                                                                                                               -------------------- ------------ ------- ----------- ----------- --------- ------------- ------------
Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller (x16) - 1901                 False        False               False       False     False             0            0
Intel - Other hardware - Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) Gaussian Mixture Model - 1911                False        False               False       False     False             0            0
Microsoft Silverlight (KB4481252)                                                                                                  False        False               False       False     False             0            0
2020-01 Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4494175)                                                           False        False               False       False     False             1            2
SQL Server 2019 RTM Cumulative Update (CU) 4 KB4548597                                                                             False        False               False       False     False             0            0
Security Intelligence Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.315.200.0)                                       True        False               False       False      True             0            0
```

### Bonus Reading

- [Windows Optional Updates Installation Issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9bc0f678-52ed-4136-8e68-9be4ba57f55a/windows-optional-updates-installation-issue?forum=winserverwsus)
- [Windows 10 Does Not Show or Install Optional Updates](https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2016/08/windows-10-does-not-show-or-install-optional-updates/)
- [How to apply optional updates on Windows 2016?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10-servicing/how-to-apply-optional-updates-on-windows-2016/m-p/204969)